# How to get the adjacency matrix of the dual of $G$ without pen and paper?

Tags: graph-theory

Given the adjacency matrix $A$ of a $k$-regular planar graph $G$ with $V$ vertices, so $A$ has dimension $V$.

> How to get the adjacency matrix $\bar A$ of the dual of $G$ without drawing the dual graph?

Using [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Euler.27s_formula) $V+F=E+2$ and $kV=2E$ (because it's $k$-regular) we get the dimension of $\bar A$ to be 
$$
F=\left(\frac k2 -1\right)V+2,
$$
but I have no idea how to fill this matrix. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [dual of a planar graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_graph) depends on how it is embedded in the plane: "The same planar graph can have non-isomorphic dual graphs." (See Wikipedia illustration.)

[image: Nonisomorphic duals of graph embedded two ways]

Although this graph is not regular, it can be modified to obtain a cubic (3-regular) graph with more than one planar embedding and associated nonisomorphic dual graphs.  Replace the left- and right-hand vertices of degree two in the top diagram with a "diamond" subgraph, connecting to its top and bottom nodes to produce all nodes of degree 3:

[image: A diamond replacing degree 2 with degree 3]

Now the outer face of the top graph will have its maximum degree 10, but the corresponding replacement in the alternative embedding yields a maximum degree 7 (shared by the outer face and one inner face).  So the dual (multi-)graph depends on the embedding and cannot be inferred only from the adjacency matrix of the original graph.

So I'd say in the general sense you've asked, it cannot be done without pencil-and-paper or some other visualization of the embedding.

Comment: +1 ok, I didn't think of that...but that unsatisfactory :-( maybe I should have added 3-connected...

Comment: Are multiple edges (more than one between two vertices) allowed? Forbidden?

Comment: Forbidden. Why?

Comment: If you add 3-vertex-connected to planar, the graph must be [polyhedral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhedral_graph), i.e. realizable as the edges and vertices of a convex polyhedron. This suggests that any planar embedding will always give rise to the same dual (e.g. the faces of that polyhedron).  Young et al (2004) give [a classification of all k-regular planar graphs](http://youngp.people.cofc.edu/psrgraphs.pdf).

Comment: Note that even if the original graph has no multiple edges, the dual might have some.

Comment: Here's [a citation](http://citeseer.uark.edu:8080/citeseerx/showciting;jsessionid=F59D36F116699724FD2DFBD7F0FC770F?cid=7957190) for "Whitney's theorem", which I find referenced in many pages, that the embedding of a 3-connected planar graph is unique up to reflection and choice of outer face.

Comment: @draks: I tweaked the Wikipedia example to be 3-regular (and argue the resulting dual multi-graphs are not isomorphic).

Comment: I'm about to repost this question due to an advice on [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/10531/19341). Do you see any other obvious obstacle than the missing 3-connectedness that would be necessary?

Comment: ...meanwhile I posted it: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/459773/19341

Comment: You mention regularity once in the body of the new question, but it should probably be worked into the title and stated as an assumption in the opening paragraph there.