# Get the adjacency matrix of the dual of a 3-connected $k$-regular $G$ without pen and paper

Tags: graph-theory

Given the adjacency matrix $A$ of a $k$-regular planar **3-connected** graph $G$ with $V$ vertices, so $A$ has dimension $V$. 3-connectedness is needed because,
*if the graph is 3-connected, then Whitney showed that the embedding, and thus the dual graph, is unique. (Source:[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_graph#Properties))*

> How to get the adjacency matrix $\bar A$ of the dual of $G$ without drawing the dual graph?

Using [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Euler.27s_formula) $V+F=E+2$ and $kV=2E$ (because it's $k$-regular) we get the dimension of $\bar A$ to be 
$$
F=\left(\frac k2 -1\right)V+2,
$$
but I have no idea how to fill this matrix. Can anyone help?

I assume $k=3$, since the case I'm mainly interested in are bicubic planar graphs consisting of squares ($4$-faces) and hexagons ($6$-faces). Further I assume $G$ to be hamiltonian, but if you can do it without, even better.

Here are my recent thoughts:

1. Since I know how to get [Returning Paths on Cubic Graphs Without Backtracking](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/177722/19341), I start with any vertex $v_0$ and propagate it like
   $$
    Ap_r(A) = p_{r+1}(A) +2 p_{r-1}(A).
   $$
   I should get back to the intial vertex, three times for three (possibly degenerate) values of $r$ according to the face degree of the faces adjacent to $v_0$. I'll do this for every vertex along the Hamilton cycle.
2. Then my idea is to use [Grinberg's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grinberg%27s_theorem) to classify the faces (and therefore the vertices of the dual graph) whether they are inside (called $a_k$) or outside ($b_k$) the Hamilton cycle. It is not hard to see that [$a_4+2a_6=\frac12V-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1381486/19341).

But here I'm currently stuck to compile the information into the according adjacency matrix of the dual graph. Is this possible?

Comment: Something to consider: Let $G$ be *self-dual*. (You'll have to drop the $k$-regularity condition to get any non-trivial cases, but keep planarity and $3$-connectedness for uniqueness purposes.) If you can find a way to "see" that $\overline{A} = A$ in this case, then you'll be in a better position to handle your question. (I don't know of such a way, myself. There must be an algorithm somewhere that crunches through this stuff, though.)

Comment: I've been looking at the construction of a dual (planar) graph "without pen and paper", and discovered that it's a pretty interesting (non-trivial) problem.  To the extent that known methods involve combinatorial search, it would be a stretch to claim these don't require pen-and-paper (arguably a computer is needed instead?).

Comment: As advised on [meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10531/19341), I'll repost this question, which is close to this [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/457335/19341), with the additional condition, that $G$ is 3-connected...