# Is the dual graph of a planar graph an isomorphism invariant?

Tags: general-topology, combinatorics, graph-theory

> Is the dual graph of a planar graph an isomorphism invariant of the graph? Or does it depend on the embedding in $S^2$?
>
> If it is an invariant, what's the proof?

Here's what I mean. Given a planar graph $\Gamma = (V,E)$, define an embedding of a planar graph to be a cell complex whose total space is homemorphic to $S^2$ and a map from $V$ to the $0$-cells and $E$ to the $1$-cells that respects the incidence structure. (An aside: note that this definition implies $\Gamma$ is connected. I know this isn't standard but bear with me.)

My understanding of the dual graph depends on such an embedding: I define $\Gamma^\vee$ to have as vertices the $2$-cells of the cell complex and as edges the $1$-cells, with an edge connecting the pair of vertices / $2$-cells to which it is incident.

My question would be answered either by a definition of the dual graph that didn't depend on such an embedding, or by a proof that there is an isomorphism between the duals resulting from any two embeddings. (**Edit:** Oh, right. *Or*, examples to show that the dual graph isn't an isomorphism invariant!)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wikipedia states that the duals corresponding to different embeddings can indeed be different, but does not give an example. **Later.** Ah. There is an example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_graph)

Comment: Wouldn't the embeddings of $K_4$ be a counterexample?

Comment: I had occasion to draw a picture of this in [one of my answers](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/457363/3111) (two planar embeddings of a graph that give distinct duals).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a graph is 3-connected and planar, then it has a unique embedding on the sphere. This a result of Whitney (see the Wikipedia article on dual graphs). If the graph is not 3-connected then, as the examples in the comments show, the embedding is in general not unique.