# Graph Theory - Duality of Non Planar Graphs

Tags: graph-theory, duality-theorems

In my lectures I have the definition of dual graphs linked to planar graphs. Is there a way to prove (or any prove already made) that I can't get a dual graph from a non-planar graph?

Comment: non-planar graphs don't have faces?

Answer (score 1):

You can embed any finite non-planar graph into surface of higher [genus](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Genus.html) (and plane is genus-0 surface) and find its dual graph using this embedding. So restriction of duality definition by planar graph only is like getting square root of non-negative numbers only, it makes sense just to simplify studying.

Edit. You can read more precise answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1585864/100361).